Git Extensions: view WEBP as images?
I made a commit that contained images in PNG and WEBP formats. I was surprised to find that Git Extentions in the commit window shows PNG as images, and WEBP as binary files. I looked in the Git Extentions settings and could not find a setting that would specify which file types to show by which viewer.
How can I change the Git Extentions settings so that it shows WEBP as images too?
